Mock a void method's inside behavior
I have interfaces which follows the visitor design pattern:
public interface VisitorContext
{
    POJOClass getMethod(); //this method returns a POJOClass object
}

public interface Visitor
{
    void before(VisitorContext visitorContext);
}

I want to test these classes in another implementation which is not necessary to share. Here is the code snippet for it
public class EngineTest
{
    private VisitorContext visitorContext = Mockito.mock(VisitorContext.class);
    private Visitor testVisitor = Mockito.mock(Visitor.class);
    private List<VisitorContext> beforeList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Test
    public doTest()
    {
        when(testVisitor.before(any(VisitorContext.class))).then(beforeList.add(visitorContext));
    }
}

I am getting this error:
'when(T)' in 'org.mockito.Mockito' cannot be applied to '(void)'

I am trying to mock the behavior inside of a void method in java, but somehow not sure how to do it. How do I mock the inside of the void method?

What is your test testing? That Mockito works? The only production class I see is ArrayList<>, everything else is replaced by test doubles. You are not testing your code, you are testing that Mockito does what it promises to do.

You trying to use when().than() on a void method, that is not possible with Mockito, Mockito provides the doAnswer method to handle such cases.

Use doAnswer to specify what should happen when the before method is called.
Capture the argument of type VisitorContext and add it to your beforeList.

Example:
public class MyTest {
    
        private VisitorContext visitorContext = mock(VisitorContext.class);
        private Visitor testVisitor = mock(Visitor.class);
        private List<VisitorContext> beforeList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @Test
        public void doTest() {
            doAnswer(invocation -> {
                VisitorContext context = invocation.getArgument(0);
                beforeList.add(context);
                return null; // void method requires returning null
            }).when(testVisitor).before(any(VisitorContext.class));
    
            // call method
            testVisitor.before(visitorContext);
    
            // verifay
            assertTrue(beforeList.contains(visitorContext));
        }
    }


This perfectly works. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.
